# Why doesn't the javascript replace global flag work in Chrome or IE, and how to I work around it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

According to the [`String.prototype.replace()` page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example.3a_Using_global_and_ignore_with_replace), I should be able to easily replace multiple patterns just by using

```
str.replace('what to replace', 'replace with', 'flags')
```

and setting the flags to `'g'`.

It works perfect in Firefox 3.6. But in Chrome and IE8, it only replaces the first `'what to replace'`.

I can use the

```
str.replace(/what to replace/gi, 'replace with')
```

syntax. But I'm pulling the `'what to replace'` out of an array, which makes it hard to add the flags in that syntax.

Here's the code I'm trying to use. How to I modify it to work in Chrome as well as Firefox?

```
function generateQuestion()
{
    //alert('variable length: '+variableList.length);
    for(i=0;i<variableList.length;i++)
    {
        variable = variableList[i];
        rep = replacementList[i];
        flags = "gi";
        questionText = questionText.replace(variable, rep, flags);
    }
}
```

And why do I have to bother modifying it at all? Shouldn't Chrome evaluate the JavaScript as described in the link?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The very page you linked to mentions:

> The use of the flags parameter in the String.replace method is non-standard. For cross-browser compatibility, use a RegExp object with corresponding flags.

Basically, it should only work on Firefox. As per the documentation, you can generate regexes dynamically using `new RegExp`:

```
var regex = new RegExp(variable, 'gi');
questionText = questionText.replace(regex, rep);
```

This will need `variable` to be escaped, however.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be something simple like that. Just needed another person to look at the problem. :D

Comment: But then you have a problem that strings for RegExp have to be escaped, which is quite error prone.

Comment: @Mitar It's unfortunate, but there's no way around that. You just have to be careful with your escaping

Answer (score 5):

It appears that webkit's implementation of string.replace perhaps doesn't have the 3rd parameter, as `'foo'.replace('o','i','g')` results in `fio` for me.

The following appears to work however:

```
'foo'.replace(/o/gi,'i')
```

Another option is:

```
'foo'.replace(new RegExp('o', 'gi'),'i')
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Mozilla Developer Network - JavaScript - String - replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Parameters)

**Non-standard**

The use of the flags parameter in the String.replace method is non-standard. For cross-browser compatibility, use a RegExp object with corresponding flags.

Working in Chrome and Firefox

To get your code to work in Chrome and Firefox, you'll have to create a RegExp object (since your strings aren't hardcoded) with the appropriate flags. See [Mozilla Developer Network - RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: But then you have a problem that strings for RegExp have to be escaped, which is quite error prone.