# Javascript: using String.replace() to replace/remove HTML anchors

Tags: javascript, string, search, replace

I am trying to accomplish a task that would be very simple if there was a way to replace one simple string with another.

I have an HTML source of a page as a string. It contains several internal anchors such as
<a href="#about">, <a href="#contact">, <a href="#top">, <a href="#bottom">, <a href="#who-we-are">, etc.

All of the anchors are stored in an array (['about','contact'],...), and I need to remove every occurance of a string like

```
href="#whatever"
```

(where whatever is each time something different) so that the result is
    <a>

What I'd do with simple search and replace would be to iterate through my array and replace each occurance of

```
'href="'+anchorname+'"'
```

with an empty string. But after many attempts with string.replace() I still have't found the way to accomplish this.

---

In other words (posted also in the comments):
A much simpler way to put my question would be this:

Suppose my string contains the following three strings

<a href="#contact"> <a href="#what"> <a href="#more">

How to I use Javascript to replace them (but NOT any tag with the same pattern) with <a> ?

Comment: Have you tried regex? http://www.advanced-javascript-tutorial.com/RegularExpressions.cfm

Comment: `astring.replace(...)` returns a value, it does not change `astring`.  You would need to use the `setAttribute` DOM function to actually change the value of a live HTML page, or use the output of `astring.replace(...)` instead of referring to `astring` again.

Comment: To make the code format like code, first right the raw code then select the code you wrote and press ctrl + k. That will do it

Comment: Try to add jquery to your page. It will make your life easier

Comment: I much simpler way to put my question would be this:

Suppose my string contains the following three strings

<a href="#contact">
<a href="#what">
<a href="#more">

How to I use Javascript to replace them (but NOT any tag with the same pattern) with <a> ?

Comment: One specific statement would be as follows: `var reptag = "thistag"; var mystring = '<a href="#thistag"> <a href="#thattag"'; var repstring = mystring.replace('a href="#' + reptag + '"', 'a');`.  Then `repstring` contains the final string.  Note the alternating single and double quote characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
All of the anchors are stored in an array (['about','contact'],...), and I need to remove every occurance of a string like href="#whatever" (where whatever is each time something different) so that the result is
```

for this you could do something like this:

```
var tets_array = $("a[href^='#']"); // select all a tags having href attr starting with #
```

Then take the array and modify with what you want.

Comment: It sounds like he has one big string value for the entire HTML content and he wants to manipulate that.  I'm guessing he doesn't have jQuery or any other libraries accessible to provide the `$(...)` access functionality.

Comment: His question is vague dont you think. It is difficult to understand

Comment: The original question was vage becuase it was the first time I asked something without knowing how to make my code appear properly. I fixed it now. The question is about using the javascript String.replace() function to replace not a general pattern but specific strings containing characters like " and #.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand the question but you can try this :

`var index = myArray.indexOf('whatever');`

myArray[index] = "whatever2"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you can replace all of those using regular expressions.

```
var tagString = '<a href="#contact"> <a href="#what"> <a href="#more">';

// Find every occurrence which starts with '#' and ends with '"'
var regEx = new RegExp('#.*?"', 'g'); 

// Replace those occurrences with '"' to remove them
tagString = tagString.replace(regEx, '"');
```

**EDIT:**

To replace specific tags in an array, you can do the following:

```
var tags = ['<a href="#a">', '<a href="#b">', '<a href="#c">'];
var tagsToReplace = ['a', 'c'];

for (var i = 0, len = tags.length; i < len; i++) {
    var matches = tags[i].match(/#.*"/);
    if (matches === null) {
        continue;
    }

    var anchor = matches[0].substr(1).replace('"', ''); // Get only the anchor
    if (tagsToReplace.indexOf(anchor) !== -1) {
        tags[i] = tags[i].replace('#' + anchor, 'replaced');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. No, I want to replace only a list of SPECIFIC anchors (stored in an array), NOT all of the substrings that match a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

One specific statement would be as follows:

```
var mystring = '<a href="#thistag"> <a href="#thattag">';
var repstring = mystring;
var myarray = ['thistag', 'theothertag'];

for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
  var reptag = myarray[i];
  repstring = repstring.replace('a href="#' + reptag + '"', 'a');
}
```

Then `repstring` contains the final string.  Note the alternating single and double quote characters which ensure that the double-quotes are in their usual place as part of the HTML text.  Obviously you can change `reptag` (i.e., the content of `myarray`) to include the `#` character, at which point you would alter the `mystring.replace(...)` line to match.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the suggestions. I tried various variations of them and noticed that some worked in Firefox but not in chrome, which led me to this thread

[Why doesn't the javascript replace global flag work in Chrome or IE, and how to I work around it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981501/why-doesnt-the-javascript-replace-global-flag-work-in-chrome-or-ie-and-how-to)

Which led me to the solution:

```
for (var i=0; i < myTags.length ; i++)
{
        var find = 'href="#' + myTags[i] + '"';
        var regex = new RegExp(find, 'gi');
        MyWholeString = MyWholeString.replace(regex, '');
}
```