# JavaScript replace all comma in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to convert all comma in below string to space or say blank, i tried below code which is only taking care of first comma, I tried global indicator /g as well but that do nothing.

What I am doing wrong?

```
var str="D'Or, Megan#LastName Jr., FirstName#BMW, somename#What, new";
str=str.replace(',','');
alert(str)
```

#### Output

> D'Or Megan#LastName Jr., FirstName#BMW, somename#What, new

#### expected

> D'Or Megan#LastName Jr. FirstName#BMW somename#What new

Comment: `str.replace(/,/g, '')`

Comment: Can also do `str.replace(',', '', 'g')`. From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace): "To perform a global search and replace, either include the g switch in the regular expression or if the first parameter is a string, include g in the flags parameter."

Comment: i tried this global option as mentioned not working for me :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BbNeK/

Comment: Thanks Andolasoft....my bad  i was using single coma for regex str=str.replace('/,/g','');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace any given string u need to use regular expressions. You need to use a `RegExp` Object to ensure crossbrowser compatibility.

> The use of the flags parameter in the String.replace method is
>   non-standard. For cross-browser compatibility, use a RegExp object
>   with corresponding flags.

```
//Init
var str = "D'Or, Megan#LastName Jr., FirstName#BMW, somename#What, new";
var regex = new RegExp(',', 'g');

//replace via regex
str = str.replace(regex, '');

//output check
console.log(str); // D'Or Megan#LastName Jr. FirstName#BMW somename#What new
```

See that fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/m1yhwL3n/1/ example. Thats how it will work fine for all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the global option in the following way:

```
str=str.replace(/,/g,'');
```

Comment: The global flag used in that way will work fine in Firefox, but not across other browsers as it is non-standard. Please see the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981501/why-doesnt-the-javascript-replace-global-flag-work-in-chrome-or-ie-and-how-to

Comment: That's what I get for skimming documentation. Good to know. Going to delete my previous comment since it's now redundant.

Comment: I can see why they introduced it, but it doesn't seem to have caught on. No worries and thanks for the upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code,

```
var str="D'Or, Megan#LastName Jr., FirstName#BMW, somename#What, new";
val=str.replace(/,/g, '');
alert(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var str="D'Or, Megan#LastName Jr., FirstName#BMW, somename#What, new";
str=str.replace(/,/g ,'');
alert(str)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bmy4C/)

Answer (score -1):

My Bad i was using comma for regex

wrong
str=str.replace('/,/g','');

good
str=str.replace(/,/g,'');

Thanks all for correct this..I will add points for all of you. :)