# Replace string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have this string:

```
1<div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>
```

if i replace the values

```
var descriptionVal = desc.replace('<div>', '-').replace('</div>', '-');
```

it will replace only the first div

```
1-2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>
```

how to replace all div?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the javascript replace global flag work in Chrome or IE, and how to I work around it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981501/why-doesnt-the-javascript-replace-global-flag-work-in-chrome-or-ie-and-how-to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use regular expressions to replace. You can use the `replace` function with global flag `g`. Checkout the following solution:

```
var descriptionVal = desc.replace(/<div>/g, '-').replace(/<\/div>/g, '-');
```

**Working example:**

```js
var str = "1<div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>";
str = str.replace(/<div>/g, '-').replace(/<\/div>/g, '-');
document.write(str);
```

With a simple string replace, like your example, only the first occurance of each `replace` function will be replaced:

```js
var str = "1<div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>";
str = str.replace('<div>', '-').replace('</div>', '-');
document.write(str);
```